# Using Python to refresh Excel - Getting error

Tags: python, win32com

I am trying to refresh the excel because i am using pivot data in it.but i am getting error

```
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

current_dir = Path.cwd()
out_file = current_dir.joinpath(destination_file)
print(f"The outfile path is {out_file}")

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb_7 = xlapp.workbooks.open(out_file)

# Refresh all data connections.
wb_7.RefreshAll()
wb_7.Save()

# Quit
xlapp.Quit()
```

Error is

```
 wb_7 = xlapp.workbooks.open(out_file)
 File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in open
 TypeError: must be real number, not WindowsPath
```

Any advise here

Answer (score 1):

Before starting, be sure that your path is correct. If you are using jupyter notebook, it will raise error. And if your excel file is in the same folder with your py script, you should use following code for assigning path:

```
pathname = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
path = os.path.abspath(pathname) + '\\'
out_file = path + out_file
```

Also, you need to use the function appropriately. Some functions start with Uppercase of letter. Use like following:

> **xlapp.Workbooks.Open**

And for healthy refreshing, I recommend you to open xlapp with specific properties, such as:

```
xlapp = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
xlapp.Interactive = False
xlapp.Application.EnableEvents = False
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = False  # Suppress any Alert windows, which require User action
xlapp.AskToUpdateLinks = False # Disable automatic update linking
xlapp.Visible = False  # Run the Application in the background
```

Refreshing

```
wb_7 = xlapp.Workbooks.Open(out_file)
wb_7.RefreshAll()
xlapp.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone()
wb_7.Save()
wb_7.Close(True)
wb_7 = None   # Unset wb_7 variable (This is to ensure it's closed)
```

And do not forget to restore original excel properties

```
xlapp.Interactive = True
xlapp.DisplayAlerts = True  # Suppress any Alert windows, which require User action
xlapp.AskToUpdateLinks = True  # Disable automatic update linking
xlapp.Application.EnableEvents = True
xlapp.Visible = True  # Run the Application in the background
xlapp.Quit()    # Close Excel
```

Comment: THanks so much Orhan. THis really helps. But i am getting below error, not sure why                        `raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (repr(self), attr))
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Application instance at 0x2584370933424>' object has no attribute 'workbooks`

Comment: Did you check that using *Workbooks*, instead of *workbooks*. Python is case-sensitive.
And for testing, just open a new excel file and try it on. If it will not raise error code is okay. Maybe there is a problem on pivot-table (invalid-reference inside) or corrupted excel issue.

Comment: Thanks Orhan. It worked. Also i changed the open to Open as well. Now the new error is       `ret = self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(1923, LCID, 1, (13, 0), ((8, 1), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17), (12, 17)),Filename
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Excel', 'Open method of Workbooks class failed', 'xlmain11.chm', 0, -2146827284), None)`

Comment: If you are using remote desktop, be sure that it's running with highest privileges. Or you could try to run cmd as administrator. And before running your code, check your task manager and kill all the EXCEL.EXE processses.